# machine learning : UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

> i am new in the machine learning. when i run the code basically i
> coped the code from the teacher's note. but i got some "userwarning"
>
> using single csv file for performing decision tree

```
data = pd.read_csv("H:\spyder python program\data_file\iris_data.csv")

data.features = data[["SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth"]]
data.targets = data.Class
```

this is where the warning show

**output**

```
 UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name 
  data.features = data[["SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth"]]
```

Comment: The error you have is because the code is trying to assign data to `data.features` if you want to do this your should do so using `data['features']` but honestly i have no idea what you are trying to do so yea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas is 'thinking' you are trying to create new columns named 'features' and 'targets'. You can't do it such way, you should use data['features'] = ... syntax.
But it's not clear what are you trying to do in general. You should be doing something like this:

```
X = data[["SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth"]]
y = data['Class']
model.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the names you have assigned, it seems that you wanna create a dataframe which only contains 4 columns you select from dataframe `data`.

If so, the warning python raises to you is to warn that `aaa.bbb` is an ambiguous way to name a dataframe， since it could also be an attribute `bbb` to a class `aaa`, just like what python describe as follows.

One compliant way to name a dataframe is like `aaa_bbb`.

And for the second code there should be another error waiting for you XD. Just describe in detail what you want to operate.